# VSTS and Agents 2013

Tags: azure-devops, testcomplete

I'm trying to leverage SmartBear TestComplete for coded UI tests as part of my release process. I found a response stating TestComplete will not work with the 2015 test agents:

> Running TestComplete Tests Remotely with Visual Studio Test Agents
>
> Test Controller
>
> Test agents for Visual Studio 2015 do not support running functional
>   tests remotely from Visual Studio. To run tests, use test controllers
>   and test agents for Visual Studio 2013. You can find more information
>   on it in the MSDN Library.
>
> •Microsoft Test Controller for Visual Studio 2013.
>       •TestComplete 12 (or TestExecute 12).
>       •TestComplete 12 Visual Studio Integration Package.    The Integration Package installer is shipped along with TestComplete.  You
>   can find it in the TestComplete folder after installing the  product: 
>   TestComplete 12\VS Integration\VSIntegration.exe    Run this installer
>   after installing TestComplete on the test  controller machine. In the
>   installation wizard, select Build and Test  Integration or Test Agent
>   Integration feature appropriate for your  test controller version.

[Ref](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/TestComplete-General-Discussions/Unable-to-initialize-TestExecute-Unable-to-connect-to-the/td-p/136160)

I tried installing the 2013 Agents Update 5, both the agent and controller on a machine. My release agent is installed on a VM on my network as well, it is not cloud hosted. I added a "Run Functional Tests" task to my release process and tried to run it, but I get an error indicating I need to run the "Deploy Test Agent" task first:

> [error]System.InvalidOperationException: The "Deploy Test Agent" task
>   should be added before running the "Run Functional Test" task.

I tried adding that, then I started getting what seems to be a network error:

> [warning]DistributedTests: Task 'PopulatingMachinesPresentState' for 
>   machine XXXXXX:5986's Log : Failed to establish remote power shell 
>   session to the deployment machine XXXXXX on the port:5986 due to 
>   unexpected exception. Error Message:
>   System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException: 
>   Connecting to remote server XXXXXX failed with the following error 
>   message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the 
>   specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over
>   the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is 
>   enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM 
>   firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote 
>   computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the 
>   about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

So I tried disabling the firewall temporarily:

> netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off

And I also checked winrm:

> winrm qc 
>   WinRM service is already running on this machine. WinRM is
>   already set up for remote management on this computer.

Still not getting this to work. I figured I'd check Stack before I get any further down the rabbit hole. Has anyone gotten Agents 2013 to work with an on-prem release agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, agents 2013 is used to do test in lab environment in MTM or remote test from Visual Studio test.

You are doing test through **Run Functional Test task** in build/release, it uses agents 2015 instead of agents 2013 and the **Deploy Test Agent task** will install and configure test agent 2015 on the target machine.

Secondly, regarding WinRM issue, you need to enable File and Printer Sharing and the PowerShell version is 4.0 or above.

Refer to this article to configure WinRM: [Deploy your Web Deploy package to IIS servers using WinRM](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-winrm).

The related script: [ConfigureWinRM.ps1](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/PowerShellOnTargetMachines/ConfigureWinRM.ps1)

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get my tests running.